# Nested objects in jqGrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid working with JSON data which have nested objects. I'm using jsonmap to set the colmodel and it's working fine; but when I try to edit a row, the JSON passed to the server only contain the jsonmap property and not the whole object, so it's not being able to map the JSON to an Java Object.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{'id': 1,
 'name': 'blah',
 'importantData':
     {'importantDataId': 145,
      'importantDataName': 'bleh'}
}
```

The jqGrid colmodel looks like this:

```
{name:'id', label:'ID', editable: false},
{name:'name', label:'Name', editable: true},
{name:'importantData_name', label:'Important Data', jsonmap: 'importantData.importantDataName', editable: false}
```

See that importantData is not editable, but has to be shown in the grid and in the form.

As I wrote, this works nice and I see "bleh" as the value in the column for "Important Data".
When I clic the edit button of the navbar grid, I see the form to edit data with current values. ID is not shown (as it's not editable), and importantData is shown as "bleh". I change the name in the form and save, and the JSON sent to the server looks like this:

```
{'id': 1,
 'name': 'newName',
 'importantData_name', 'bleh'}
```

The server can't parse this JSON as it expects to receive the whole object importantData or at least its ID.

I have configured a serializeEditData function to retrieve the whole object from the grid and add to the JSON the whole object or de ID, but I can't get the whole importantData object. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done is to use the method serializeEditData of the jqGrid and set it to overwrite importantData_name.
It's like this:

```
serializeEditData: function (postData) {
    postData.importantData = myImportantData;
    var data = JSON.stringify(postData, function(key, value) {
        if(key == importantData_name) {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, I avoid "importantData_name" to be included in de JSON and I include a new property, "importantData", with the whole object.
I have to save the whole object when I load the jqGrid for use it in this point.

Hope this helps someone else.